# how to force a string in a label to have 2 decimal places

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, label, decimal-point

may I know if there is any way to force a string to have 2 decimal point? Let's say I have these prices. $20, $43.2. How do I make sure that these prices will be $20.00 & $43.20. I've seen through many links, but none of them worked for this situation. Please help!!

Comment: Better you vote one of answer that helped you ..

Answer (score 1):

For a decimal to display as currency with two decimal points in C# use myDecimal.ToString("C2");

Comment: Sorry I missed that tag, in VB use .ToString("C2") without the semicolon. Also, based on your culture settings you may need to use .ToString("C", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: what's culture settings? :/

Comment: Culture settings can be used to globalize applications... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaa7b9c0(v=vs.71).aspx Don't be afraid to do a little googling.

Answer (score 1):

Use ToString() and specify format as an argument:

```
Dim d As Decimal = 20D
Dim s As String = d.ToString("0.00")
's will now contain "20.00"
```

Use # instead of 0 if you want to omit unsignificant digits. Another example:

```
Dim s As String = 10.ToString("#,##0.00")
's will now contain "10.00"
s = 10.ToString("0,000.##")
's will now contain "0,010"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use FormatCurrency() function ..

```
FormatCurrency(20, 2) '------> result $20.00 -- $ sign depend on your regional setting
```

You can see it here ... http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_format_currency.html